# Download all files of a certain type without directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, recursion, wget

I am trying to download all ".m4a" podcast files from this base URL "http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/" and ignore ones that have already been downloaded.

This is my current code (it doesn't search subdirectories)

```
#!/bin/bash
lynx --dump 'http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/' | awk '/http/{print $2}' >> temp.txt
while read link || [[ -n "$link" ]]; do
    if [[ $link == *m4a ]]
    then
        if grep -q $link usedlinks.txt; then
            echo "This episode has already been downloaded!"
        else
            wget $link
            echo $link >> usedlinks.txt
        fi
    else
        echo "Non-audio file detected!"
    fi
done < temp.txt
rm temp.txt
```

(I would also like to rename the downloaded files to a certain pattern, I don't know if you could help with that, too?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need in scripting at all. All you had to do -- to read a `wget` man page :)

```
wget -np -nd -c -A.m4a -r -k -erobots=off http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/
```

For mass file rename there is a `rename` tool ( check which one you have as it depends on your distro  before you use it)

---

The full instruction how to handle this download. First download can be performed with:

```
wget -np -nd -c -A.m4a -r -k -erobots=off http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/ \
-o download.log
```

now we have all download log in file. to form a blacklist for future download we need to build a file list from a log:

```
v_black_list=$(sed -n '/--.*m4a/s=.*/==p' download.log | tr '\n' ',')
```

and to run wget with this enabled black list, you have to use `-R` option:

```
wget -np -nd -c -A.m4a -r -k -erobots=off http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/ \
-a download.log -R$v_black_list
```

note, that in second run `-a` is used instead of `-o` to avoid logfile overwrite.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to be able to only download each file once.

Comment: `-c` option will check if you already have a file and if it is completely downloaded `wget` will skip it. obviously, you should not rename the file before the full download is finished.

Comment: I need to store that information inside a text file because I want to be able to delete the files after I have listened to them.

Comment: There is still an option. You can save all the `wget` output to a file with `-o file.log` option. and then grep it with `grep -- --.*m4a` to get a file list. or even grep directly `wget` output with: `wget ....  2>&1 | grep -- --.*m4a`

Comment: I can't seem to make it work, could you give me an example command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wget to scrape the website for you in one line. It canl download all of the *.m4a files for you and save then in directories like they are stored on the website. Here is a basic command to get you started, but you will need to tune the options to do exactly what you want:

```
wget -r -H -l1 -np -N -A.m4a -erobots=off http://runawaypodcast.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/
```